# How can I make the PDO object make it available in any section of the code(in objects, functions, methods, scripts etc.)?

Tags: php, object, pdo

Database connection

```
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass='';
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=resource_management', $db_user, $db_pass);
```

Here the User class it's created

```
class User{     
    protected $username;
    protected $pass;
    public function __construct($username, $password){
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }   
    public function test(){     
        $sql = "select * from user";
        $data = $db->query($sql);
        while ($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            var_dump($row);
            echo $row->username;
        }
    }   
}
```

Here I try to test the User class

```
$user = new User('admin', 'test');
$user->test();
```

Comment: such thing as PASSWORD must never be part of your code.. its only place is inside login/register functions.

Once you have logged user you can fetch it usually with saved user id in a Session..

Comment: I hope next line isn't `if ($password == $row['password'])` (;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd normally pass it in the constructor or use a factory pattern that autoloads the arguments:

```
class Factory{
  public static function setdb($db) {
    self::$db = $db;
    }

  public static function getUser($role, $action) {
    return new User(self::$db, $role, $action);
    }

  public static function getUserPermissions($role, $action) {
    return new UserPermissions(self::$db, $role, $action);
    }
  }
```

Something like that. Note: I'm not a patterns expert and right now I'm learning about it, so the code above might contain bugs/not be perfect. Then you'd access it like:

```
$DB = new PDO(...);
factory::setdb($DB)

$User = Factory::getUser('admin', 'test');
```

I think the code is self-explanatory. Then you can add other methods to create more objects and automatically pass them the required variables so you don't need to be writing them all manually. It's called the **Factory pattern**. You can add more methods as you wish.

Note2: while *globals* is something that might come to mind, it's a [terrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why).